# SDK Manager in Android Studio shows no packages

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I want to install **Google Images** in **Android Studio**, so I can create an emulator (when creating emulator, it says that there are no Google Images), so I searched all around the web, and all it says there, is to go to SDK manager and install the Google Images.
So I went to the SDK manager & unchecked the filter for obsolete packages, and tried everything, but no packages are coming up.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're trying to download a system image for your Android emulator and you couldn't download it using the SDK manager, you can try this way: Go to `AVD manager - Create virtual device` then select your skin either it is custom or default by the AS then see if there are any system images available or not. This is the best approach since you'll need to define which type of system images you need (with or without the Google APIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was a rare one.
I have a **internet filter** on my computer that blocks a lot of sites, like **Facebook / TikTok**, and some URLs where **Android Studio** fetches the packages were blocked, so nothing came through.

The solution was to **request an unblock** from the filtering company (in my case [Techloq](https://www.techloq.com/)) to let any URL coming from **Android Studio** go through.